# VBA Excel create hour column (like in a calendar) according to given time resolution

Tags: datetime, excel, vba

I need to create some sort of a calendar in VBA.
I need to create a column of hours. The time difference between 2 adjacent cells is determined by an integer read from a text file, which represents the time resolution in minutes.

For example - if Res = 60, the hour column should look like this:

```
12:00
13:00
14:00
 ...
```

if Res = 30, the hour column should look like this:

```
12:00
12:30
13:00
13:30
14:00
 ....
```

I've calculated the number of cells according to the given resultion (if Res = 60, nCells = 24, if Res = 30 nCells = 48 and so on). I just don't know how to create the hour column (in VBA code of course).

Thanks,
Li

Comment: actually say if you have `12:00` in A1, when you drag that cell down, `13:00` and `14:00` are automatically created. Likewise, if you have `12:00` and `12:30` in A1 and A2, same thing happens when you drag down

Comment: I know but I want to code it in VBA, given the time resolution...

Comment: As a hint, consider the following. Enter "12:00" into A1, enter "13:00" into A2, enter "=A2-A1" into A4. You should get a 'result' of 1:00. Now, change the formatting of A4 - change it from "Custom h:mm" to General. Now you see a result of 0.0416666667. That looks like about 4.2% 4% is one in 25 - Hmm, perhaps this 0.041 is the increment needed for one hour, when added to the numerical representation of a time/date. So, if you convert 12:00 in A1 to also be formatted as "General", you get 0.5 i.e `12/24 = 0.5` minsIncrement = (mins / 60) / 24. I.e 30 mins = 0.5 / 24 = 0.0208 (1/2 of A4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DateAdd to increment dates:  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

```
Sub createTimeColumn()

intIncr = 60                                    'minutes to add each cell
intCellCnt = 1440 / intIncr                     '24h * 60m = 1440 minutes per day
datDate = CDate("01/11/2013 06:00:00")          'start date+time for first cell

For i = 1 To intCellCnt                         'loop through n cells
    Cells(i, 1) = Format(datDate, "hh:mm")      'write and format result
    datDate = DateAdd("n", intIncr, datDate)    'add increment value
Next i

End Sub
```

Result will look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple loop to which you pass the start range, begin & end time and increment. I recommend to strictly work with dates/times; the output range should be formatted as time

```
Sub CallTest()
    FillIt [A1], #12:00:00 PM#, #1:00:00 PM#, #12:10:00 AM#
End Sub

Sub FillIt(RStart As Range, TStart As Date, TEnd As Date, Inc As Date)
Dim Idx As Integer, TLoop

    Idx = 1
    TLoop = TStart

    Do
        RStart(Idx, 1) = TLoop
        TLoop = TLoop + Inc
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop Until TLoop > TEnd + #12:00:01 AM# ' need to add 1 second to really
                                            ' break the loop where we want

End Sub
```

Don't worry about the somewhat strange looking `Inc` parameter .... in VBA editor just enter `#0:10:0#` ... it will automatically expand to a full 24 hrs AM/PM notation.

The 1 second in the Loop Until is added because I found that the loop is left 1 pass too early (it seems that within the loop `#16:0:0# < #16:0:0#` resolves to `True`)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to only use the time resolution to do so. True, I have the start time, but I want to be able to create a time column for each resolution I read. For example, if the resolution is 30 min, and the start time is 12:00, I want the second cell to show 12:30 and the last cell to show 11:30. But if the resolution is 60 min I want the second cell to show 13:00 and the last to show 11:00.

Comment: so just read the start time from the worksheet and pass it over to the function ... and play with the other parameters accordingly (like `TEnd = TStart + #12:0:0#`) ... this is a programming platform ... show some efforts now ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub MakeTime(RangeA As Range, iRes As Long)
Dim dDate As Date
Dim rCell As Range
Dim X As Variant
Set rCell = RangeA
dDate = CDate(RangeA.Value)
Do
    dDate = DateAdd("n", iRes, dDate)
    Set rCell = rCell.Offset(1, 0)
    rCell.Value = dDate
Loop Until DateDiff("h", CDate(RangeA.Value), dDate) >= 24
End Sub

Sub test()
Call MakeTime(Sheet1.Range("A1"), 45)
End Sub
```

They beat me to it...  But since I've already written a routine...  Might as well post it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a new workbook

```
Sub Main()

    ' ask for column input
    Dim myColumn As String
    myColumn = InputBox("Please enter the column letter where the hours will be stored")

        ' Clear the column
        Columns(myColumn & ":" & myColumn).ClearContents

    ' initial hour
    Dim firstHour As String
    firstHour = InputBox("Please enter the start time in the hh:mm format i.e. 12:00")

    ' interval
    Dim interval As Long
    interval = CLng(InputBox("Please enter the interval in minutes"))

    ' duration
    Dim duration As Long
    duration = CLng(InputBox("Please enter the duration (hrs)"))

    ' apply formatting to column
    Columns(myColumn & ":" & myColumn).NumberFormat = "hh:mm;@"

    ' enter the initial time into cell
    Range(myColumn & 1) = CDate(firstHour)

    ' fill in remaining hours / interval
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To (60 / interval) * duration
        Range(myColumn & 1).Offset(i, 0) = DateAdd("n", interval, CDate(Range(myColumn & 1).Offset(i - 1, 0)))
    Next i

End Sub
```